# How to treat given integer as binary values?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I have a integer value i.e. 1010110. How to treat this value as binary? So that i can find the integer value of that binary value.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `base` parameter (`2` in this case) to the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
s = "1010110"
i = int(s, 2)
# 86
```